# Converting a List to Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I got a list of Strings that i want to convert to a map. I tried the below but i can't seem to figure out why its not working

```
List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>( //code to create the list );

Map<String, Double> doubleMap = dataList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(o->o, Double::new));
```

All i get is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Test1"
```

It seems to be trying to put a string into the value (which is a Double) instead of creating an empty/null double.

I essentially want the map to contain the String, 0.0 for each record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to pass a `String` to the `public Double(String s)` constructor, which fails if your `List` contains any `String` that cannot be parsed as a `double`.

When you pass a method reference of a `Double` constructor to `toMap`, it's equivalent to :

```
Map<String, Double> doubleMap = dataList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(o->o, o->new Double(o)));
```

Instead, write :

```
Map<String, Double> doubleMap = dataList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(o->o, o->0.0));
```

Comment: That is interesting, so i always have to pass the object (in this case o) and indicate what it is to be going forwards?

Comment: @Aeseir No, you can use a method reference, but the method referred by this reference will get the element of the Stream as an argument (if it's a reference to a static method or to a constructor, which is what happened in your code snippet) or be executed on each element of the Stream (if it's an instance method).

Comment: Tanks for the input, solved a lot of other problems along the way

Comment: There is no sense in creating a new `Double` object representing the same zero value for each mapping. While `o->0.0` may or may not create a new `Double` instance each time, the constructor reference will always create a new object for sure. It might be even better to box once, `Double zero=0.0;`, before the operation and use `o->zero` as value mapping function.